# What happened to the Chat SE joining/leaving animation?

Tags: support, chat, design

In StackExchange chat, there used to be an animation when a user joined or left a chatroom. In the little group of favicons below the chatroom name:

[image: tnb]

When a user joined, their favicon would float from the top towards that list. When they left, it would float from that list to the bottom left.

In [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte), I haven't noticed the animation for about a week, using Chrome/Chromium. [It's also happening on Safari.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39187617#39187617) However, as mentioned in the comments, it works fine in an English SE chatroom.

What happened to our animation?

**Edit:** This appears to be an issue with certain users in The Nineteenth Byte, regardless of operating system.

Comment: Stupid question, but did people leave and join in that time? They may have been 'inactive' but not actually gone.

Comment: Reproduced with actual joining / leaving. Upvote if you have also (independently) reproduced.

Comment: @marcellothearcane Nope, we [tested it out](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39187550#39187550), each leaving in turn.

Comment: I just floated in to https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-usage... do I down vote this, @wizzwizz4?

Comment: @MD XF yup, I saw you...

Comment: @marcellothearcane That's odd.

Comment: @marcellothearcane What setup?

Comment: @MDXF What setup?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 59.0 (Official Build), Windows 7

Comment: @marcellothearcane - If others are showing the issue being reproduced, it is probably not appropriate to downvote, even if your setup is not reproducing it. Just my opinion.

Comment: @TravisJ Okay, unsure what to do in these situations (thought that if you upvote when you have it, maybe you downvote when you don't)  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 8):

This is by-design for rooms with a lot of currently active users. It's all explained by a single line out of the JavaScript file:

```
n = n && a.find("li.present-user").length <= 32, void 0 == s && (s = now());
```

`n` must be true in order for the user arriving and parting animations to fire. In order for `n` to be true, there also has to be 32 or fewer users currently in the list.

I can only conclude that at the time there were more than 32 users in the room.

Comment: Planning to become a developer instead of CGOS? ;)

Answer (score 4):

### People seem to encounter this issue using:

- Firefox 54.0.1 on Windows x86_64 in [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240).
- Chrome  59.0.3071.115 on Windows x86_64 in [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240).
- Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.18737 on Windows x86_64 in [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240).

### People seem to not encounter this issue using:

- Chrome 59.0.3071.115 on Windows x86_64 in [English Language Usage](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-usage).
- Chrome 59.0.3071.115 on Windows x86_64 in [The Stack Exchange Network](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11254/the-stack-exchange-network).
- Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.18737 on Windows x86_64 in [The Stack Exchange Network](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11254/the-stack-exchange-network).
- Chrome 59.0.3071.115 on Windows x86_64 in [Cubically](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62883/cubically).
- Firefox 54.0.1 on Windows x86_64 in [The BBS](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38597/the-bbs).
- Chrome 59.0.3071.115 on Windows x86_64 in [talk.tryitonline.net](https://talk.tryitonline.net).
- Chrome 59.0.3071.115 on Windows x86_64 in [NOT THE SUPER SEKKRIT ARQADE MODERATERING ROOM](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56355/not-the-super-sekkrit-arqade-moderatering-room).

Comment: Looks like it's probably The Nineteenth Byte that's having issues...

Answer (score 3):

This issue appears to be isolated to The Nineteenth Byte. This is strange, because it shares a stylesheet with other beta-style chatrooms. The issue may be linked to the activity of the room causing lag for some users, meaning that the animation does not properly display or fails to display at all.

Comment: On that note, I saw someone float out of The Nineteenth Byte... ([ErikTheOutgolfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41024/erik-the-outgolfer))

Comment: @marcellothearcane What OS/version?

Comment: @MDXF sorry, `Chrome 59.0.3071.115 on Windows x86_64`. I didn't see myself float in though...